# Ext.net: how to load data in a form when row grid change?

Tags: asp.net, extjs, ext.net

i've a gridview and a form panel in the same page (the form panel contains the detail of  data). 
I would like to "load" data into form panel after the user click on a row of the grid...
Is it possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following examples might help to get you started, see

http://examples.ext.net/#/GridPanel/Data_with_Details/Form_Details/

http://examples.ext.net/#/DragDrop/Grid/Grid_to_FormPanel/

http://examples.ext.net/#/GridPanel/Miscellaneous/Details_Window/

Comment: Hi Geoffrey, thank you. I'm trying to develop with your wonderful (really, it's great) framework... my only problem is about the documentation! Ok, you made a lot of examples, but i think something like a book, or tutorial is more ...efficent! Can you "link" me some page with tutorial ? Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out saki's Ext examples ? He has some good code examples that could help you. Check out "Complex Data Binding" in Application Design http://examples.extjs.eu/